# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running Spark program using spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cloudera

I have written a following Spark program in Scala. I exported it as JAR file. When I run it in Cloudera Spark cluster using spark-submit command, it is giving me Class Not found error.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object AirflowFileReader extends App {
  
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  sparkConf.set("spark.app.name" , "load and filter a csv file")
  sparkConf.set("spark.master" , "local[2]")
  
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config(sparkConf)
  .getOrCreate()
  
  val ordersDf = spark.read
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("path", "airflow_input_nw/orders.csv") 
                .load();

  val ordersDf1=spark.sql("select * from orders where order_status='CLOSED'")
  
  ordersDf1.write.format("csv").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("path","airflow_output").save()

  
  
}
```

Command to execute in Cloudera Quickstart terminal -

```
spark-submit --class AirflowFileReader /home/cloudera/sparkpractice.jar
```

Error -

```
[root@quickstart cloudera]# spark-submit --class AirflowFileReader
/home/cloudera/sparkpractice.jar Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession   at
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  at
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)  at
java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)     at
java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)  at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:715)
    at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession   at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)  at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   ... 9 more
```